# Count of full outer join in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I'm trying to display the total number of rows in a full outer join table. I have the following code, but mysql says there is an error with duplicate columns. The 2 tables, actors and directors, have the same columns as they are supposed to provide similar information in their respective categories.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
(SELECT * FROM directors LEFT OUTER JOIN actors
ON directors.name = actors.name
UNION
SELECT * FROM directors RIGHT OUTER JOIN actors
ON directors.name = actors.name) AS table1;
```

What can be done to fix the code so it will run properly? FYI, the code from within the parenthesis runs fine. The problem only arises once I put in the SELECT COUNT(*) clause.

Comment: What is the exact error message from MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Becuase there are two `name` columns one is from `directors` table, another is from `actors` table, and you `select *` that will let DB engine confuse which name did you want to get.

if you only want to `count` total number you can try this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
(
    SELECT directors.name FROM directors LEFT OUTER JOIN actors
        ON directors.name = actors.name
    UNION
    SELECT directors.name FROM directors RIGHT OUTER JOIN actors
        ON directors.name = actors.name
) table1;
```

**NOTE**

I would suggest use `select` clear the columns and avoid using `select *`

Comment: There could be only two names in the database and hundreds of records.

Comment: Millions of data are not mentioned in the OP, the problem with this OP is How to solve the error.

Comment: Ah, I see your point now, without knowing the rest of the columns you cannot really say more than name; my concern is more with "bob" could appear multiple times with different data in the other columns, and this would merge all "bob" records down to one.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to change the right join portion non-redundant, and just add separate 
counts.

Generic version:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.x = B.x) 
+ (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B LEFT JOIN A ON B.x = A.x WHERE A.x IS NULL)
AS outerJoinSize
;
```

Note: I changed the RIGHT JOIN to a LEFT JOIN and swapped the tables around; in my experience, RIGHT JOIN just tends to make queries a little harder to read (especially when multiple joins are involved).

---

An completely different alternative...

```
SELECT 
( SELECT SUM(dc1.c * IFNULL(ac1.c, 1)) AS jc
  FROM (SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS c FROM directors GROUP BY name) AS dc1 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS c FROM actors GROUP BY name) AS ac1
     ON dc1.name = ac1.name)
+ (SELECT SUM(IF(dc2.name IS NULL, ac2.c, 0)) AS jc
   FROM (SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS c FROM actors GROUP BY name) AS ac2
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS c FROM directors GROUP BY name) AS dc2 
      ON ac2.name = dc2.name)
```

...this one figures out how many matches based on the joining field (3 instances of "Bob" in directors and 2 in actors means 6 join results for that name).

Comment: Your counts aren't equivalent to the count of the UNION  see this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b538c5/5

Comment: I'll have to look, but I was going with trying to get the count of a cross join; which a UNION [DISTINCT] cannot necessarily replicate.

Comment: My calculated outerJoinSize looks right according to the cross join I worked out in my head with that data; the current UNION ALL in the fiddle doesn't work out to the same answer because the second query of the union needs to eliminate duplicates from the first with `WHERE a.x IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are getting at with the `full join`.  But the best way to implement it in MySQL uses two `left join`s and a `union`:

```
select count(*)
from ((select name from directors) union -- on purpose
      (select name from actors)
     ) da left join
     directors d
     on da.name = d.name left join
     actors a
     on da.name = a.name;
```

If I had to guess, though, you just want the number of distinct names between the two tables.  If so:

```
select count(*)
from ((select name from directors) union -- on purpose
      (select name from actors)
     ) da
```